# Refactor JS Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this ugly chunk of code which is responsible for positioning some sub-navigation on a website and I want some opinion on how I could improve it, because even I admit it's ugly as hell :)

Maybe someone has a better structuring idea, because I don't due to the complex logic :

```
positionSubItems : function() {
        var $that = $(this),
            $parent = $that.parents().eq(1),
            $elements = $parent.find(' > li'),
            $activeElements = $parent.find(' > li.active'),
            $container = $that.parent().find(".expandedViewContainer"),

            highestBoundary = $($elements[0]).offset().top - $($elements[0]).outerHeight(true),
            lowestBoundary = $($elements[$elements.length - 1]).offset().top + $($elements[$elements.length - 1]).outerHeight(true),
            containerHeight = $container.outerHeight(true),
            elementHeight = $that.outerHeight(true),

            returnIndex = function(selector) {
                return $(selector).parent().index();
            };

        if($that.data().subItemsPositioned !== true) {

            $container.css({
                'margin-top' : - ( containerHeight / 2 + (elementHeight / 2) )
            });

            if((lowestBoundary - highestBoundary) <= containerHeight) {
                $container.css({
                    'margin-top' : - ((elementHeight * 2) + (elementHeight * returnIndex($that)) + ($activeElements.find(" > ul").outerHeight(true) || 0))
                });
            }

            if($container.offset().top < highestBoundary) {
                $container.css({
                    'margin-top' : - ((elementHeight * 2) + (elementHeight * returnIndex($that)))
                });

                if((lowestBoundary - highestBoundary) < containerHeight) {
                    $container.css({
                        'margin-top' : - ((elementHeight * 2) + (elementHeight * returnIndex($that)) + ($activeElements.find(" > ul").outerHeight(true) || 0))
                    });
                }
            }

            if(($container.offset().top + containerHeight) >= lowestBoundary) {
                $container.css({
                    'margin-top' : - ( containerHeight - (elementHeight * ($elements.length - returnIndex($that))) )
                });

                if((lowestBoundary - highestBoundary) <= containerHeight) {
                    $container.css({
                        'margin-top' : - ((elementHeight * 2) + (elementHeight * returnIndex($that)) + ($activeElements.find(" > ul").outerHeight(true) || 0))
                    });
                }
            }

            $that.data().subItemsPositioned = true;
        }

    }
```

So just let me briefly explain what it does. Let's say we have a left vertical navigation ( a vertical list of `li` ). In those `li`s we have a link and another div which also contains another list of items. So what this function need's to do it's position this sub level of `li`s according to some rules :

- there are two boundaries, one upper which corresponds to the most upper 'li' item on the first level plus it's own height, and the other one lower which corresponds to the most low `li` on the first level plus it's own height
- the first condition would be that always position the sub items, which are held by a container and displayed to the right of the parent `li`, so the parent it's shown in the middle of that container
- based on the above rule, if the offset of the resulted positioning of the container exceeds the upper boundary, then reposition the container so the top offset of the container it's now at the same level as the upper boundary
- continuing to click on the rest of the items follow the first rule, apply the second one if it's the case, then if this following condition it's meet apply it : when the offset of the bottom of the container exceeds the lowest boundary, reposition it so the bottom of the container it's always at the same level as the lowest boundary
- after going through all of the above rules and conditions you also have to check if the height of the container is bigger than the height between the upper and lower boundary, in that case apply the first rule, position the container at the same level as the upper boundary
- there is also another scenario encountered, if there are to few parent `li`s and the height of the container now exceeds the height of the height between boundaries again, so we'll have to apply the just above mentioned rule
- and there is another scenario which I won't describe as I'm already to deep into details

So stating the above, I hope someone has a better way of doing all the logic and maybe a more cleaner way too :)

Comment: @roasted ~ the first one it's so I can go two levels up and find some specific elements, and the second one it's so I can go just one level up :)

Comment: Ya sorry i've made a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing if the underlying logic makes sense, this is slightly easier to read in my opinion

```
if(!$that.data().subItemsPositioned)  {
  var  offset=0;
  var ulOuterHeight = (elementHeight * 2) + (elementHeight * returnIndex($that)) + ($activeElements.find("  >  ul").outerHeight(true) ||  0);
  switch(true)  {
    case (lowestBoundary - highestBoundary)  <=  containerHeight  :
      offset = ulOuterHeight;  
      break;
    case $container.offset().top  <  highestBoundary  :
      if((lowestBoundary - highestBoundary)  <  containerHeight)  {
        offset = ulOuterHeight; 
      }
      else offset = (elementHeight * 2) + (elementHeight * returnIndex($that))
      break;
    case ($container.offset().top + containerHeight)  >=  lowestBoundary  :
      if((lowestBoundary - highestBoundary)  <=  containerHeight)  {
        offset = ulOuterHeight; 
      }
      else offset = containerHeight - (elementHeight * ($elements.length - returnIndex($that)));  
      break;
    default: offset = containerHeight/2 + (elementHeight/2);
  }
  $container.css({'margin-top'  : - offset  });
  $that.data().subItemsPositioned = true;
}
```

Comment: @mplungian ~ the problem in this case is that I first need to set the position as centered and then check if the other cases apply ... or at least this is how it goes in my head :)

Answer (score 1):

this piece of code seems to be always the same, try to put that out of the if conditions (probably into a function):

```
$container.css({
    'margin-top' : - ((elementHeight * 2) + (elementHeight *     returnIndex($that)) + ($activeElements.find(" > ul").outerHeight(true) || 0))
});
```

i think that should be a good point to start. look for lines of code which are duplicate

Answer (score 1):

here is some kind of example (without exactly reading what your function does, just some refactorings to dry this function a little bit up

this is still some kind of ugly but i hope it helps to push you into the right direction

```
positionSubItems : function() {
    var $that = $(this),
    $parent = $that.parents().eq(1),
    $elements = $parent.find(' > li'),
    $activeElements = $parent.find(' > li.active'),
    $container = $that.parent().find(".expandedViewContainer"),

    highestBoundary = $($elements[0]).offset().top - $($elements[0]).outerHeight(true),
    lowestBoundary = $($elements[$elements.length - 1]).offset().top + $($elements[$elements.length - 1]).outerHeight(true),
    containerHeight = $container.outerHeight(true),
    elementHeight = $that.outerHeight(true),

    returnIndex = function(selector) {
        return $(selector).parent().index();
    },

    containerCSS = function(marginTop) {
        $container.css({
            'margin-top' : - marginTop
        });
    },

    doTheMarginTop = function() {
        containerCSS((elementHeight * 2) + (elementHeight * returnIndex($that)) + ($activeElements.find(" > ul").outerHeight(true) || 0));
    };

if($that.data().subItemsPositioned !== true) {

    containerCSS(containerHeight / 2 + (elementHeight / 2));

    if((lowestBoundary - highestBoundary) <= containerHeight) {
        doTheMarginTop();
    }

    if($container.offset().top < highestBoundary) {
        containerCSS(((elementHeight * 2) + (elementHeight * returnIndex($that))));

        if((lowestBoundary - highestBoundary) < containerHeight) {
            doTheMarginTop();
        }
    }

    if(($container.offset().top + containerHeight) >= lowestBoundary) {
        containerCSS( containerHeight - (elementHeight * ($elements.length - returnIndex($that))) );
        if((lowestBoundary - highestBoundary) <= containerHeight) { doTheMarginTop(); }
    }

    $that.data().subItemsPositioned = true;
}
```

}